# How to filter records with multiple condition based on stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a school management system. I just created a stored procedure for retrieving a list of students from the database. If I just pass in null to all parameters, the stored procedure works fine, but when I add some parameter values, then I get this error:

> Msg 50000, Level 15, State 1, Procedure GetStudentList, Line 91
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'and'

Here is my stored procedure code:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetStudentList]
    (@rollno VARCHAR(5) = NULL,
     @name VARCHAR(25)= NULL,
     @classid INT = NULL,
     @sectionid INT = NULL)
AS
    DECLARE @qry NVARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)  
    DECLARE @rollcond NVARCHAR(5)  
    DECLARE @namecond NVARCHAR(25)  
    DECLARE @classcond NVARCHAR(10)
    DECLARE @sectioncond NVARCHAR(10)
BEGIN
BEGIN TRY
    SET @qry = N'select PK_PID as ID,
       StudentName as Name
      ,Gender 
      ,FatherName as Parents
      ,Address
      ,format(DOB,''dd/MM/yyyy'') as DOB
      ,EmailID
      ,AdmissionDate
      ,(select [ClassName] from dbo.classes where classes.PK_PID = s.Class) AS Class   
      ,(select [SectionName] from dbo.sections where sections.PK_PID = s.Section) AS Section   
      ,RollNo
      ,MobileNo
      ,Active   
      ,StudentPhoto
  from dbo.students s where 1=1'

  IF @rollno is null  
  BEGIN  
      SET @rollcond = ''  
  END  
  ELSE  
  BEGIN  
      SET @rollcond = ' and s.RollNo like ''%'+@rollno+'%'' '  
  END

  IF @name IS NULL
  BEGIN  
      SET @namecond = ''  
  END  
  ELSE  
  BEGIN  
      SET @namecond = ' and s.StudentName like ''%'+@name+'%'' '  
  END

  IF @classid IS NULL 
  BEGIN  
      SET @classcond = ''  
  END  
  ELSE  
  BEGIN  
      SET @classcond =' and s.Class = '+CONVERT(INT,@classid)+' '    
  END

  IF @sectionid IS NULL
  BEGIN  
      SET @sectioncond = ''  
  END  
  ELSE  
  BEGIN  
      SET @sectioncond =' and s.Section = '+CONVERT(INT,@sectionid)+' '    
  END

  SET @sql = @qry + @rollcond + @namecond + @classcond + @sectioncond
  --+' order by ID asc '

  EXEC sp_executesql @sql
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH 
    DECLARE @ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(4000); 
    DECLARE @ErrorSeverity INT;
    DECLARE @ErrorState INT;

    SELECT 
        @ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE(), 
        @ErrorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY(),
        @ErrorState = ERROR_STATE();

    RAISERROR (@ErrorMessage, -- Message text.
               @ErrorSeverity, -- Severity.
               @ErrorState); -- State.
END CATCH;
END
```

What's going wrong here? Please guys help me...

**----------------updated------------------------**

```
USE [SM_00001]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[GetStudentList]    Script Date: 11/7/2019 8:56:52 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetStudentList]
(
    @searchtext varchar(200) = null,
    @classid int = null,
    @sectionid int = null
)
AS
BEGIN

--new script
select [PK_PID] as ID,
     [StudentName] as Name
    ,[Gender] 
    ,[FatherName] as Parents
    ,[Address]
    ,format([DOB],'dd/MM/yyyy') as DOB
    ,[EmailID]
    ,[AdmissionDate]
    ,C.[ClassName] as Class   
    ,Section.[SectionName] as Section
    ,[RollNo]
    ,[MobileNo]
    ,[Active]   
    ,[StudentPhoto]
from [dbo].[students] as s 

outer apply (select isnull([ClassName],'Default Class') from [dbo].[classes] where [classes].[PK_PID] = s.[Class]) as C
outer apply (select isnull([SectionName],'Default Section') from [dbo].[sections] where [sections].[PK_PID] = s.[Section]) as Section 

where (@searchtext is null  or s.[StudentName] LIKE '%'+@searchtext+'%'
                            or s.[Gender] LIKE '%'+@searchtext+'%'
                            or s.[FatherName] LIKE '%'+@searchtext+'%'
                            or s.[Address] LIKE '%'+@searchtext+'%'
                            or s.[DOB] LIKE '%'+@searchtext+'%'
                            or s.[Address] LIKE '%'+@searchtext+'%'
                            or s.[MobileNo] LIKE '%'+@searchtext+'%'
                            or s.[EmailID] LIKE '%'+@searchtext+'%')

and (@classid is null or s.[Class] = CONVERT(INT,@classid))
and (@sectionid is null or s.[Section] = CONVERT(INT,@sectionid))


--old script
--select PK_PID as ID,
--    StudentName as Name
--    ,Gender 
--    ,FatherName as Parents
--    ,Address
--    ,format(DOB,'dd/MM/yyyy') as DOB
--    ,EmailID
--    ,AdmissionDate
--    ,(select [ClassName] from dbo.classes where classes.PK_PID = s.Class) AS Class   
--    ,(select [SectionName] from dbo.sections where sections.PK_PID = s.Section) AS Section   
--    ,RollNo
--    ,MobileNo
--    ,Active   
--    ,StudentPhoto
--from dbo.students s order by ID asc
END
```

i just get sql error here :

```
Msg 8155, Level 16, State 2, Procedure GetStudentList, Line 36
No column name was specified for column 1 of 'C'.
Msg 8155, Level 16, State 2, Procedure GetStudentList, Line 38
No column name was specified for column 1 of 'Section'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure GetStudentList, Line 27
Invalid column name 'ClassName'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure GetStudentList, Line 28
Invalid column name 'SectionName'.
```

**-----------------------update 2--------------------------**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[students](
    [PK_PID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [StudentName] [varchar](25) NULL,
    [Gender] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [FatherName] [varchar](25) NULL,
    [MotherName] [varchar](25) NULL,
    [DOB] [datetime] NULL,
    [Religion] [varchar](15) NULL,
    [BloodGroup] [varchar](5) NULL,
    [FatherOccupation] [varchar](25) NULL,
    [EmailID] [varchar](150) NULL,
    [AdmissionDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [AdmissionID] [varchar](25) NULL,
    [Class] [int] NULL,
    [Section] [int] NULL,
    [RollNo] [varchar](5) NULL,
    [Address] [varchar](200) NULL,
    [BIO] [varchar](200) NULL,
    [MobileNo] [varchar](15) NULL,
    [PhoneNo] [varchar](15) NULL,
    [Active] [bit] NULL,
    [Entry_By] [int] NULL,
    [Enty_date] [smalldatetime] NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_students_Enty_date]  DEFAULT (getdate()),
    [StudentPhoto] [image] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_students] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [PK_PID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[classes](
    [PK_PID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ClassName] [varchar](25) NULL,
    [Entry_By] [int] NULL,
    [Entry_Date] [smalldatetime] NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_classes_Entry_Date]  DEFAULT (getdate()),
 CONSTRAINT [PK_classes] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [PK_PID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[sections](
    [PK_PID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [SectionName] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [Entry_By] [int] NULL,
    [Entry_Date] [smalldatetime] NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_sections_Entry_Date]  DEFAULT (getdate()),
 CONSTRAINT [PK_sections] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [PK_PID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: Print your @sql statement at the end, see what it looks like.

Comment: Try to print the generated script first and then execute the printed script. You will then able to get the issue hopefully.

Comment: @Andrew can u please post your code for how print it.

Comment: There is absolutely no reason to use dynamic sql here, just structure your sql correctly and use the parameters directly.

Comment: Please don't update your question in a way that invalidates answers. It makes the stream of questions and answers very hard to understand. Ask a second question if the first has been answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also go with `outer apply` instead of 'inline query'

For more details [Click here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/f0b2ed/cross-apply-and-outer-apply-in-sql-server/)

Also, refer here some concepts [Click here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1958/sql-server-cross-apply-and-outer-apply/)

This is a far better way to write your query, that does not use dynamic SQL:

Here your stored procedure code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetStudentList]
    (@searchtext VARCHAR(200) = NULL,
     @classid INT = NULL,
     @sectionid INT = NULL)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT
        [PK_PID] as ID,
        [StudentName] as Name,
        [Gender], 
        [FatherName] as Parents,
        [Address],
        FORMAT([DOB], 'dd/MM/yyyy') AS DOB,
        [EmailID],
        [AdmissionDate],
        C.[ClassName] AS Class,
        Section.[SectionName] AS Section,
        [RollNo], [MobileNo], [Active], [StudentPhoto]
    FROM
        [dbo].[students] AS s 
    OUTER APPLY 
        (SELECT 
             ISNULL([ClassName], 'Default Class') AS ClassName  
         FROM
             [dbo].[classes] 
         WHERE
             [classes].[PK_PID] = s.[Class]) AS C
    OUTER APPLY
        (SELECT ISNULL([SectionName], 'Default Section') AS SectionName 
         FROM [dbo].[sections] 
         WHERE [sections].[PK_PID] = s.[Section]) AS Section 
    WHERE
        (@searchtext IS NULL OR 
         s.[StudentName] LIKE '%' + @searchtext + '%' OR 
         s.[Gender] LIKE '%' + @searchtext + '%' OR
         s.[FatherName] LIKE '%' + @searchtext + '%' OR
         s.[Address] LIKE '%' + @searchtext + '%' OR
         s.[DOB] LIKE '%' + @searchtext + '%' OR
         s.[Address] LIKE '%' + @searchtext + '%' OR
         s.[MobileNo] LIKE '%' + @searchtext + '%' OR
         s.[EmailID] LIKE '%' + @searchtext + '%')
      AND (@classid IS NULL OR s.[Class] = CONVERT(INT, @classid))
      AND (@sectionid IS NULL OR s.[Section] = CONVERT(INT, @sectionid))
END
```

Here is your query that you want it

```
SELECT [PK_PID] AS ID,
    [StudentName] AS Name
    ,[Gender] 
    ,[FatherName] AS Parents
    ,[Address]
    ,FORMAT([DOB],'dd/MM/yyyy') AS DOB
    ,[EmailID]
    ,[AdmissionDate]
    ,C.[ClassName] AS Class   
    ,Section.[SectionName] AS Section
    ,[RollNo]
    ,[MobileNo]
    ,[Active]   
    ,[StudentPhoto]
FROM [dbo].[students] AS s 
outer apply (select isnull([ClassName],'Default Class') AS ClassName  from [dbo].[classes] where [classes].[PK_PID] = s.[Class]) as C
outer apply (select isnull([SectionName],'Default Section') AS SectionName from [dbo].[sections] where [sections].[PK_PID] = s.[Section]) as Section 
WHERE (@rollno IS NULL  OR s.[RollNo] LIKE '%'+@rollno+'%' )
AND (@name IS NULL OR s.[StudentName] LIKE '%'+@name+'%')
AND (@classid IS NULL OR s.[Class] = CONVERT(INT,@classid))
AND (@sectionid IS NULL OR s.[Section] = CONVERT(INT,@sectionid))
```

Comment: i have just upadated my question please see.

Comment: Sure let me check

Comment: If possible please add your table script `Student, Class, Section`

Comment: Wait I'll do example

Comment: Please check the updated code. with your store procedure and query, changes has been done

Comment: here i just want @searchtext from all required table columns. please see my last update2...

Comment: I suspect a simple join on Classes and Section would be simpler here - dont know why you would use an outer apply instead?

Comment: Outer Apply nothing but one of `table type function` in SQL.

OUTER APPLY in SQL Server. OUTER APPLY returns both rows that produce a result set, and rows that do not, with NULL values in the columns produced by the table-valued function. OUTER APPLY work as LEFT OUTER JOIN

For more details please see here https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/f0b2ed/cross-apply-and-outer-apply-in-sql-server/

Comment: Yes exactly, so why not just use LEFT JOIN instead? I personally think APPLY is way overused - it was designed to be used for table functions and other use cases that couldn't be done using joins, not in place of simple joins.

Answer (score 2):

This is a far better way to write your query, that does not use dynamic sql:

```
select PK_PID as ID,
    StudentName as Name
    ,Gender 
    ,FatherName as Parents
    ,Address
    ,format(DOB,'dd/MM/yyyy') as DOB
    ,EmailID
    ,AdmissionDate
    ,(select [ClassName] from dbo.classes where classes.PK_PID = s.Class) AS Class   
    ,(select [SectionName] from dbo.sections where sections.PK_PID = s.Section) AS Section   
    ,RollNo
    ,MobileNo
    ,Active   
    ,StudentPhoto
from dbo.students s 
where (@rollno is null  or s.RollNo like '%'+@rollno+'%' )
and (@name is null or s.StudentName like '%'+@name+'%')
and (@classid is null or s.Class = CONVERT(INT,@classid))
and (@sectionid is null or s.Section = CONVERT(INT,@sectionid))
```